# Symlink to socket file when running docker container doesn't work

Tags: docker, sockets, symlink, docker-volume, rootless

It seems that symlinks to socket is not correctly handled by docker run.

**The problem:**

I'm trying to use rootless docker. The socket to connect to docker is
/run/user/1000/docker.sock.

But I need to use a docker-compose file where a traefik container is run with a volume mapping to give access to /var/run/docker.sock from inside the container. I can't modify this docker-compose file.

To make it work, I tried to do a symlink /var/run/docker.sock > /run/user/1000/docker.socket. It works fine on my host machine, I can talk to the rootless docker using this socket but when running the container, the /var/run/docker.sock file is not a socket but a directory.

**How to reproduce:**

To reproduce the problem with docker run:

```sh
sudo ln -s /run/user/1000/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock
sudo docker run -v /run/user/1000/docker.sock:/var/run/docker-user.sock -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it traefik /bin/sh
```

Inside the traefik container:

```sh
/ # ls -al /var/run/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            54 Dec 13 17:23 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           134 Dec 13 17:23 ..
srw-rw---T    1 root     974              0 Dec 13 15:06 docker-user.sock
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            40 Dec 13 15:09 docker.sock
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The symlink won't translate well into the container.  Can you directly mount the alternate socket path on the host into the normal socket path in the container; `docker run -v /run/user/1000/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`?

Comment: Yes, mounting directly the alternate socket works fine. I was hopping there is a way for docker to follow the symlink before creating the container :(